# Is setIgnoreRepaint delegated to children?

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I have a JFrame and inside this JFrame, I put a jPanel by calling frame.add(somePanel). Then I set frame.setIgnoreRepaint(true). Is this delegated to it's child (jPanel), or do I need to call setIgnoreRepaint for somePanel separately ?

Comment: It's a good pratice put a Frame inside another?

Comment: 1) I'm doubt, why, is there any reason etc... no idea from this description, 2) by default paintChildren() isn't called from Component.paint() / JComponet/paintComponent(), then repaint is ..., 3) no idea about your Component tree, is there custom RepaintManager 4) for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: guisantogui: I do not put frame into a frame but JPanel into frame.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am actively painting into my JPanel by directly calling overridden paint() method. I want to know what is best practice - setting "ignore repaint" just for the JPanel or whole window ?

Comment: sounds terribly wrong ... usually that's _not_ how you do custom painting in swing (have a look at the articles referenced in the swing tag wiki)